# Using iMac Bluetooth keyboard and mouse with MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, imac, bluetooth

I got iMac and I got 2 MBP, usually I use my laptop. But for each I have to use its own keyboard and trackpad or magic mouse, is there is any way to make them use just one keyboard and mouse e.g use I can use my iMac keyboard and MagicMouse with my laptop. I tried to make the iMac keyboard and Mouse discoverable by my MBP but bluetooth shows empty.

Is there a way that is possible as sometimes I use my iMac as an extended screen of my laptop.

Comment: AFIK keyboard can be paired to only one device at time.

Comment: You could try getting a Logitech mouse & keyboard with support for multiple simultaneous devices

Comment: Can I use  iMac key and mouse for my MBP, tried pairing them with MBP but it won't pick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's not possible to have the same mouse work on both your iMac and your MacBookPro simultaneously, but you can boot your iMac in [target display](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592) mode. It becomes a monitor for your MBP therefore allowing you to use your mouse on both connected screens.

Additionally, it sounds like you are having trouble connecting your mouse to your MBP. Make sure your iMac is off, or your mouse is disconnected from the iMac, before trying to connect your mouse to your MBP.

Comment: The target display doesn't work. My imac is 2017. the link says it cannot on 2014 and later and I also have 5k.

Comment: Ah. I didn’t know that. I guess it’s not supported on 2017 iMacs. Sorry about that!

Comment: The document does say I need a thunderbolt to thunderbolt. Whereas I got usb c to HDMI. I wonder why it didn’t work.